# Can we pass method parameter of controller optional

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel and I have a question running on my mind.

Basically, we create a Controller method like this:

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    if(!empty($user)){ ... }
    ...
}
```

And we call this method by passing the `$user` as parameter to this method.

But is it possible to call the parameter optional. I mean if `$user` didn't pass, still the method works.

So in order to do that, do we have to create two web routes? Because by default, when we pass parameter we have to define that too in the route uri:

```
Route::get("/{user}", "HomeController@index");
Route::get("/", "HomeController@index");
```

So how to do this in Laravel? Is it possible or not?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks.

Comment: Route::get("/user/{user?}", "HomeController@index"); otherwise both url match so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a method parameter optional, yes. That's a PHP feature:
[PHP - default function/method parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

So in your code:

```php
public function index(User $user = null)
{
    if(!empty($user)){ ... }
    ...
}
```

It seems you want to call `HomeController@index` in both cases, isn't that misleading? If you visit /1 it will load user with ID 1 and show the homepage. What could be the use-case of that?
As John Lobo suggested, the route should better be `/user/{user}` to remove that ambiguity.

**As an aside: Use Auth to get current user**

If this is meant to load the current user: You can load the current user in every controller with `Auth`. There is no need to pass the user explicitly as a parameter if that works better for you:

```php
$user = Auth::user();
```

See [Laravel docs: Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated)